# twitter-boostrap horizontal form validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

this is an example of an horizontal from

```
    <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The password and confirmation password:" id="InstanceID" name="MainSearchModel.InstanceID" placeholder="Enter instanceID..." type="text" value="" />


    <input id="MainSearchModel_ServiceName" name="MainSearchModel.ServiceName" placeholder="Enter serviceName..." type="text" value="" />
```

I am trying to valid the form,  but when I am  using  bootstrap **class="control-group"**  and **jQuery-Live-Form-Validation-For-Twitter-Bootstrap** it creates empty space for the error description  as you can see here [from after adding class](http://jsfiddle.net/miko5054/MFFz8/).

what is the best way to validate an horizontal form?

how can I make the the message to appear at the bottom of the textbox instead of appear at
the right side of the textbox ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use this button to check the validation and disable AJAX and CLIENT validations of the form:

```
$this -> widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
            'buttonType' => 'ajaxSubmit',
            'icon' => 'ok',
            'url' => Yii::app() -> createUrl('hr/userTime/create'),
            'label' => 'Submit',
            'ajaxOptions' => array('success' => 'function(data){
                    var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
                    if(obj.status=="success"){
                        $("#newUserTime").modal("hide");
                        setTimeout(function(){location.reload(true);},400);
                    } else {
                        $("#userTime-form-error-div").show();
                        $("#userTime-form-error-div").html("");
                        var $inputs = $("#user-time-form :input");
                        $inputs.each(function() {
                            $(this).removeClass("error");
                            $(this).closest(\'div[class^="control-group"]\').addClass("success validating");
                        });
                        for (var p in obj) {
                            if(document.getElementById(p)) {
                                $("#"+p).closest(\'div[class^="control-group"]\').removeClass("success");
                                $("#"+p).closest(\'div[class^="control-group"]\').addClass("error");
                            }
                            $("#userTime-form-error-div").append(obj[p]  + "<br/>");
                        }
                    }
                }'),
    ));
```

hope this will help someone to get a nice highlight of valid and error fields!